# SwiftUI ForEach Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-form

My code is simple:

```
struct ListView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { _ in
          CellView()
          Spacer()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct CellView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Template Text Template Text Template Text Template Text ")
  }
}
```

But it shows the error:
[image]

If I comment `Spacer() or CellView()`, it works good

On the other hand I have another code at different place that compiles fine:
[image]

Why could it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be single view inside `ForEach`, so wrap them in some stack, like

```
ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { _ in
  HStack {
     CellView()
     Spacer()
  }
}
```